# Bootstrap 5 my col-md-5 classes doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a 5-2-5 column layout for md and bigger sizes. bs5 seems to ignore my `col-md-5` classes, behaves like `col-12` on all sizes. It should be very simple but I couldn't find the problem in code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 mb-5">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block col">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 text-md-end mb-5">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: unexpected appearance]

[image: still col-12 applied at width=1024]

Comment: You overrule your `.col-12` and `.row>*`somewhere in your index file : in head: <style id="jch-optimize-critical-css">

Comment: It seems like a problem with jch extension.

Comment: which specific version?

Comment: jch 7.0.1, bs 5.0.2